# Browser to Spotify syncing data

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I want to make it so on my site a user goes to for example

```
http://example.com/connect/spotify
```

Then they press "Connect" and if they do, the spotify app recieves the API keys.

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you using the Spotify apps api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link to `spotify:app:myappname:key:value:key2:value2:etc:etc` to have the Spotify app launch and load your application. The `key:value:key2:value2:etc:etc` portion will then be passed to your app via the `ARGUMENTSCHANGED` even on `application`.

However, this isn't a very elegant solution at all, especially if the user hasn't got Spotify or your application installed.

A better approach might be to write a simple REST API that your Spotify app can interact with to get API keys for the other API that needs keys. That way everything will be seamless.